# Zappa project and virtualenv have the same name

Tags: django, aws-lambda, web-deployment, zappa

When running

```
zappa deploy dev
```

I get this error:

```
Warning! Your project and virtualenv have the same name! You may want to re-create your venv with a new name, or explicitly define a 'project_name', as this may cause errors.
```

Would renaming virtualenv be a safer route or renaming the project? How do I define a project_name explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not yet deployed, it would be easier to change your project's name.  Just edit `zappa_settings.json` and add a key of `project_name` as documented at https://github.com/zappa/Zappa